# 404 header - HTTP 1.0 or 1.1?

Tags: http, http-status-code-404, header

Why does almost every example I can find (including [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437256/sending-a-404-error-in-php) from about a year ago) say that a 404 header should be `HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found` when we've really been using HTTP 1.1 for over a decade?  Is there any reason not to send `HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found` instead?

(Not that it matters all that much... I'm mostly just curious.)

Comment: About 11 million Google results for `1.0`, about 4.3 million results for `1.1`.  I guess that means use `1.0`.

Comment: That question didn't say the header should be HTTP/1.0. It was only used in that example. so don't assume =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The usage of HTTP version can be based on the following factors:

- Your web server support for HTTP 1.0 or 1.1
- The web browser's support for HTTP 1.0 or 1.1
- Your preference as a web developer on which protocol version to use

Modern browsers can support both 1.0 and 1.1 well, and both the client and server will settle for the highest version both can support together. The key differences between the 2 protocol can be found: http://www8.org/w8-papers/5c-protocols/key/key.html

However there's no key differences in the usage of 404 Not Found. However do be consistent for your whole website. i.e. if you use HTTP/1.1, you use it throughout your website.

Answer (score 30):

In PHP you should probably use:

```
header( $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']." 404 Not Found", true );
```

or even better

```
header( $_ENV['SERVER_PROTOCOL']." 404 Not Found", true );
```

(if supported) and thus leave it to the web-server which protocol to use.

Actually, if you pass the status code as 3rd parameter, you can pass whatever you want in the 1st one, as long as it's not empty, and PHP will do the rest. See http://php.net/header

```
header("foobar", true, 404 );
```

Also: You can't *request* a certain protocol version from the client-side since the transaction is hop-to-hop based, and not end-to-end. The server and your browser may very well use HTTP/1.1, but if a proxy inbetween is using only HTTP/1.0, that's what you will see from your client.

Comment: Is there anyway to grab the *raw* headers sent by the client? By that, I mean line by line headers.

Comment: @Pacerier I don't know about RAW headers, but they're all part of the $_SERVER array.

Comment: No I mean I want to get the text headers before they are being parsed into the array.

Comment: either http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php or parse $_SERVER (keys who begins with HTTP_)

Comment: In what situation -is- `$_ENV['SERVER_PROTOCOL']` supported? I only got an undefined on my apache 2.4 on php 5.5

Comment: In case you've set that environment variable on your server. It also depends on if the PHP ini setting `variables_order` contains an `E`.

Answer (score 2):

It does not matter all that much.  The client is responsible for telling the server which version of HTTP it uses.  Then, the server is supposed to answer with the same version.  This does not always happen; I just got this response from a server:

```
$ telnet example.com 80
Trying 123.123.123.123...
Connected to example.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /fork HTTP/1.0

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Length: 1635
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 04 May 2010 22:30:36 GMT
Connection: close
```

I asked the server to use HTTP 1.0, but it went ahead and responded with HTTP 1.1.

Answer (score 2):

I'd have thought that the response should be `HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found` if the request was a HTTP 1.0, and `HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found` if the request was HTTP 1.1.

In practice, it's going to be easier for servers to returned canned responses, and the HTTP 1.0 response will be understood by both 1.0 and 1.1 clients, so safest to return that. If you know the client understands 1.1 (e.g. because that's what it asked for), then the 1.1 response should work.

Arguably, play it safe and send the 1.0 response.

Comment: Yep, no need to use 1.1 when you're not using any 1.1 features

Answer (score 1):

Looking at both the 1.1 and 1.0 RFCs, 404 is there in both - so it's probably for no other reason than for the server to communicate to the client that it's operating on http 1.1.

That said - if a server responds with 404 over Http 1.1, it implies that it could have returned [410 - Gone](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.11) instead to indicate a resource that used to exist but no longer does.  This status code is not part of 1.0, and therefore this information *could* be useful to a client (especially web crawlers).

**EDIT**

Sorry - this answer is probably answering the other way around!  I reckon you can probably count on only a few hands the number of public web servers that will be bothering to remember all the resources that used to exist and which no longer do (no way I'd code that into my web server!) - so therefore it's probably best to respond with the 1.0 404 to indicate that 'it's just not there' rather than 'that's not here, but other stuff around the site might used to have been but no longer - in which case I could have sent you a 410'.

There's also the fact that you're allowing 1.0-only clients to work with your site.

That said - it's all a bit pedantic.

Answer (score 1):

With modern versions of PHP you can also use the [`http_response_code`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php) function and sidestep the problem entirely!

I also like this method because it means that there's no risk of making typos in the response message.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I used "avio_http_serve_files", which is an HTTP server. It is given as example in ffmgeg (see ffpmeg git).

The syntax to start the server is (for example):

```
./avio_http_serve_files mymovie.mp4 http://192.168.1.42:10000
```

At client side:

```
vlc  ou mpv ou...
vlc http://192.168.1.42:10000/mymovie.mp4
```

If the file mymovie.mp4 is not int the server's current directory, you have the error "HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found".

You can neither use absolute directory.