# Is using HTTP 1.0 bad practice?

Tags: http, http-1.1, http-1.0

I'm implementing a basic http client for communicating with a web service and am wondering if I should go with http 1.0 or 1.1.
The data section will consist of binary data and the remote server will always be controlled by me (running IIS7.5). The firewalls / proxies inbetween is nothing I'm controlling, ie. the packets must not be stopped if wrong http version is used.

I've been reading up about the [difference between http 1.0 and 1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246859/http-1-0-vs-1-1) and it seems to me that http 1.0 supports everything I need.

Will I encounter problems if i choose http 1.0 over 1.1 or can I assume that everything will work just as good?

What makes me wonder is that if I connect via raw sockets to IIS7.5 and send a http 1.0 get request, [the response is always http 1.1.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769371/404-header-http-1-0-or-1-1/2769402#2769402)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A firewall certainly will not block it and a router will route it.

I would suggest using HTTP 1.1. Chances are nothing will be affected if you use HTTP 1.0. However, you never know who else might use your HTTP client in the future and what horrible server implementation it will be used with.

You also need to ask yourself why you are implementing an HTTP client in the first place. Why not just use a standard library? I do not know what language you are using, but `libcurl` has bindings for many languages.

You can see more about `libcurl` [here](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/).

Comment: I will use it in an embedded environment, in c, so the more lightweight it gets the better. Do you know any library that is a little less generalized than libcurl since its just the http part I need?

Comment: When you build curl, you can tell it which protocols to include. Is that good enough for your situation?

Comment: I will take a look into it, until I know something better I will accept your answer. Thanks for the help...

Comment: What about [http tiny library](http://www.demailly.com/~dl/wwwtools.html)? It lacks in recommendations which makes wonder if it is the right choice.

Comment: I don't know. I have never used it. I have only used cURL. However, I did come up with another option. Depending on what you are doing, it may be easier to use a command line utility like wget. You can call it from your script and receive the webpage from the program's standard out. I normally do this with shell scripts but it should work for a C program as well. There is a windows binary that is only half a megabyte in size.

Comment: Finally, I've decided to roll my own library. The porting of libcurl was far too tedious for my platform (compiler and os combination) and when it comes to using an unknown, unsupported library I could as well roll my own as patching someone elses to do what I want (proxy, ssl and such).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's anything wrong using 1.0 as a client, most web servers are backward compatible.

If you're really have concerns, send 1.1 and only deal with stuff you want to handle, I don't think there's anything possibly go wrong choose either case.