# PHP header HTTP 1.0 vs 1.1

Tags: php, http, header, http-headers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [404 header - HTTP 1.0 or 1.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769371/404-header-http-1-0-or-1-1)

Should you use

```
header( "HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found", true, 404 );
```

instead of

```
header( "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found", true, 404 );
```

when the user agent uses HTTP/1.0? That is, is it good to reply with the same HTTP version?

Btw, I'm using it to claim that a page doesn't exist to users currently not logged in. I understand that it is different versions and that HTTP/1.1 has different functions.

Comment: @Matt Ball I've read the answers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769371/404-header-http-1-0-or-1-1 but I feel that they don't answer whether it is a good practice to reply with HTTP/1.1 if the client uses it. I mean, the next request could go faster if the web server replies with HTTP/1.1 due to connection limits in HTTP/1.0.

Comment: @Matt Ball More correctly, the answers there actually recommend to always reply with HTTP/1.0. I agree that this could actually be a duplicate.

Comment: @Matt I guess I got the same answer here, but my question was maybe not so clear. I thought of the benefits of using HTTP/1.1. Maybe the answers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769371/404-header-http-1-0-or-1-1 could be improved, since no more answers are allowed here.

Comment: @Richard86 are there benefits of using HTTP/1.1 if the client uses it?

Comment: Read the current **HTTPbis** specification. http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p1-messaging-14#page-15 - HTTP/1.x versions are supposed to behave equally. It also lists some advise for dealing with different client versions. -- Btw, PHP and Apache filter your Status: line anyway. If in doubt, use `HTTP/1.0` and don't be bitten by semantic differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to distinguish between 1.0 and 1.1 and want to send a static header, I guess

```
header( "HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found", true, 404 );
```

is the safe way to do it - every client speaks HTTP/1.0.

But I also expect that no client at all checks the http version in case of a 404. At least, I never experienced problems with the http version...

Comment: Does this mean the connection will no longer support HTTP 1.1 features like persistent connections? Sending HTTP 1.0 as a blanket rule seems lazy and unwise to me, especially for 404 pages that include CSS and other external assets.

Answer (score 1):

When the user agent says it uses HTTP 1.0 (specified in RFC 1945 dated May 1996) you should not assume that it understands a protocol that was developed later (like HTTP 1.1 specified in RFC 2616 dated June 1999). So use HTTP 1.0 in the reply.