# PHP to check file exist on external server using file_get_contents()

Tags: php, file-io, file-get-contents

Checking file exists on external server using file_get_contents() method, does this method will work properly?

```
$url_file = "http://website.com/dir/filename.php";
$contents = file_get_contents($url_file);

if($contents){
echo "File Exists!";
} else {
echo "File Doesn't Exists!";
}
```

Comment: No, you cannot check for file existence. URLs do not reference files, just resources (which may or not originate from actual files). You can check for returned content, or [`$http_response_header`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php) states though. And you could concretise how you concluded your code does not work, or what you're really trying to accomplish.

Comment: that will check if the file has a content or not. You can try other ways to test if the file exits testing just the headers (check HTTP error codes): http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php

Comment: @lepe: I have control for that files, I can set file has a content or not.. so can I using this method?

Comment: @Ajie Kurniyawan: Yes it could work depending on your web server settings. The web server may respond with HTML: <h1>Error 404: Not found</h1> , for example, so it may have a content, but it may not be what you are expecting. I think its easier to check the headers, don't you think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think best method for me is using this script:

```
$file = "http://website.com/dir/filename.php";
$file_headers = get_headers($file);
```

If file not exists output for `$file_headers[0]` is: `HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found` or `HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found`

Use strpos method to check 404 string if file doesn't exists:

```
if(strpos($file_headers[0], '404') !== false){
echo "File Doesn't Exists!";
} else {
echo "File Exists!";
}
```

Thanks for all help :)

Comment: There are other failures besides 404.

Answer (score 1):

This would work for what you are looking to do. As seen here http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php#75064

```
$file = 'http://www.domain.com/somefile.jpg';
$file_headers = @get_headers($file);
if($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
    $exists = false;
}
else {
    $exists = true;
}
```

Comment: In my test if file not exists $file_headers[0] get value = 'HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found', so this method not works properly, should I change 1.1 to 1.0?

Comment: This all depends on the web server. Here is a good article on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769371/404-header-http-1-0-or-1-1

For me personally, I'd probably do some string manipulations to find 404 in the string and ignore the rest of the string so it would work in both cases.

Comment: If I add this script maybe this method will works?

$string = $file_headers[0]; 
$404 = "404";
$pos = strpos($string, $404);

if ($pos === false) {
     echo "File Exists!";
} else {
     echo "File Doesn't Exists!";
}

Comment: @Ajie Kurniyawan: close, don't name your variable: $404, name it for example: $code or use "404" without a variable. (numeric variables are not allowed in PHP). Fixing that, it should work.

Comment: @lepe: thanks, I have created an answer for my own question, I think best way is that method.. thanks all for help :)

Answer (score 0):

Both answers from [blamonet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25355296/) and [Ajie Kurniyawan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25356177/) are somewhat correct but there are more failures than 404(3xx, 4xx, 5xx responses). There are a lot of HTTP responses that would fail to "get/download" a file from a given server.

So I would suggest to check if `200 OK` response.

```
$file = "http://website.com/dir/filename.php";
$file_headers = @get_headers($file);

if ($file_headers) {
  if (strpos($file_headers[0], ' 200 OK') === true) {
    echo "File Exists";
  } else {
    echo "File Doesn't Exist, Access Denied, URL Moved etc";
    //you can check more responses here 404, 403, 301, 302 etc 
  }
} else {
  echo "Server has not responded. No headers or file to show.";
}
```