# header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found'); not doing anything

Tags: php, header, http-status-code-404

I have a 404.php file in my site's main directory and I was using `header('Location: 404.php');` for a while until someone said that you should use `header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');` instead. So I replaced it with that and then added: `ErrorDocument 404 /404.php` to my apache config file and restarted the server but it doesn't work.

I tried different variations including `ErrorDocument 404 404.php` and `ErrorDocument 404 mywebite/404.php` but to no avail.

What I mean by doesn't work is that earlier when using `header('Location: 404.php');` it would redirect to the 404.php file but when I replace it with `header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');` it seems to just skip over the line and not do anything. It most certainly is not redirecting. The reason I am calling for the redirect is because if a $_GET header value is not recognized the page should 404.

Comment: What does it do? Does it display Apache's 404 page?

Comment: "Someone said..." and you listened?

Comment: 404.php displays my custom 404 page and HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found just does nothing. The php file just continues on like nothing happened.

Comment: I believe ErrorDocument is only relevant when Apache doesn't know where to send a request.  If it sends a request to a script, and that script choses to return a 404 header, apache will not invoke a second 404 script -- it will simply return the output of the initial script.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why won't my PHP app send a 404 error?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/437256/952580)

Answer (score 106, accepted):

No, it probably is actually working. It's just not readily visible. Instead of *just* using the `header` call, try doing that, then including `404.php`, and then calling `die`.

You can test the fact that the `HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found` works by creating a PHP file named, say, `test.php` with this content:

```
<?php

header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
echo "PHP continues.\n";
die();
echo "Not after a die, however.\n";
```

Then viewing the result with `curl -D /dev/stdout` reveals:

```
HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found
Date: Mon, 04 Apr 2011 03:39:06 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.2
Content-Length: 14
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

PHP continues.
```

Comment: Is there any reason then why not just to do a single header('Location: 404.php'); call instead of doing that and calling HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found first?

Comment: @John: If a file wasn't found, it's technically wrong to say "oh, I found that document; it's over here" when you're just redirecting to a page informing them that it wasn't found. To be semantically correct, you have to send the `HTTP/1.x 404 Not Found` and *not* redirect.

Comment: But that doesn't do anything..? Sorry if I'm missing something but doesn't the semantic version not work in my situation?

Comment: @John: Well I was saying you should be 1. sending the HTTP thing, 2. including your `404.php` (not redirecting to it), and 3. calling `die` in that order.

Comment: Ah, I understand you now. That actually works quite well and since no redirect is required it is also very efficient! Thanks.

Answer (score 34):

You could try specifying an HTTP response code [using an optional parameter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php):

```
header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found', true, 404);
```

Comment: Not doing anything for me.

Comment: Not doing anything for me either.

Comment: Not doing anything for me.

Answer (score 21):

Since PHP >= 5.4 you can use the following function to set the HTTP status code :

```php
http_response_code(404);
```

you will still have the control over the content of the response but with the status code being 404 (you can have any status code you want).

[http_response_code  PHP Documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php)

Answer (score 10):

Use these codes for 404 not found.

```
if(strstr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'index.php')){
  header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
  readfile('404missing.html');
  exit();
}
```

Here 404missing.html is your Not found design page. (it can be .html or .php)

Answer (score 4):

i think this will help you

**content of .htaccess**

ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
ErrorDocument 400 /error.php
ErrorDocument 401 /error.php
ErrorDocument 403 /error.php
ErrorDocument 405 /error.php
ErrorDocument 406 /error.php
ErrorDocument 409 /error.php
ErrorDocument 413 /error.php
ErrorDocument 414 /error.php
ErrorDocument 500 /error.php
ErrorDocument 501 /error.php

*error.php and .htaccess should be put in the same directory [in this case]*

Comment: if you are using WAMP this should be putted in to the WWW directory

Answer (score 2):

Another reason may be if you add any html tag before this redirect.
Look carefully, you may left DOCTYPE or any html comment before this line.