# PHP - Header 404 not triggering htaccess ErrorDocument

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, errordocument

This isn't my exact PHP as it's rather complicated, but it's the same general idea.

```
if($_GET['page'] == ".htaccess"){
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
}
```

When this happens, Apache doesn't load the 404 page set in the .htaccess file. I know the 404 works because when I go to a non-existent page, I get the specified 404 page.

Is there any way I can get the specified 404 page to load without manually dumping the contents of the 404 page file?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5534268/headerhttp-1-0-404-not-found-not-doing-anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Apache already determined that the file actually exists, it wont look for 404 again.

One workaround could be actually sending a `Location`-header to a actual non-existant page and let Apache handle it. Another could be fetching the 404 page contents through PHP and outputting it together with a `Status: 404`-header

Comment: I was afraid of that. I'll let this question sit for a day or two and see if any magical hacks have been found, but if not I'll accept this.

Answer (score 0):

This may Work

```
if (strstr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'.htaccess')){
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');   
    exit();
}
```