# Php 404 Not Found Header

Tags: php, header

I am trying to understand the combination of 3 simple php code lines,
This is the code:

```
ob_end_clean();
header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
exit;
```

So this is the code and as i understand the first line **ob_end_clean();**, Can help for example with **BOM(Byte order mark)**, So the first line is to prevent any previous output.

The second line **header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');** is the header.

And the third line **exit** terminates the script execution.

If i remove the first line and i got a **BOM** at the document i get blank page (No 404).

If i remove the third line (**with and without the BOM**), I get the page i wanted no blank page and no 404.

- Mabye if anyone can explain why should i use the **exit** After the
  404 header
- Also why with the **BOM** i dont get "headers already sent error"

Thank you all and have a nice day.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why won't my PHP app send a 404 error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437256/why-wont-my-php-app-send-a-404-error)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> If i remove the first line and i got a BOM at the document i get blank
>   page (No 404).
>   you get blank 404 because you have no content defined in there...

```
header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
```

is only giving notice that user is on 404 error page site...
if you want to display some 404 notice for user you can do this by loading your 404.html file

```
if(strstr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'index.php')){
  header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
  readfile('404missing.html');
  exit();
}
```

or directly

```
if (strstr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'index.php')){
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
    echo "<h1>Error 404 Not Found</h1>";
    echo "The page that you have requested could not be found.";
    exit();
}
```

exit function is there because you have to prevent execution of another php code, which may be directly after `if` or which may be excecuted later, simply it says `END`

Comment: Hey Lukas as i understand your if statement is for the code work only on index pages.

Comment: No, it's apache definition of 404 page... I don't know what's the situation of your code, you can use only content of `IF` statement. Notice: header is message for 'robots', 'crawlers' and echo is message for 'humans' ...

Comment: Thank you for your answer Lukas, Can you tell me please why the browser parse and shows the 404 only if i kill the rest of the script?

Comment: Also i tryed to understand your if statement, And as i say i tested and it return index.php string, Also what do you mean when you say "you can use only content of IF statement", Thank you and have a nice day.

Comment: it seems that your php is still in process, php will not print output until it finished execution (reach end of php file). You have to stop it manualy by exit. If you want to execute some php on 404 page.. do it before sending `head` and `echo`.. Execution of basic php may take miliseconds, user will not notice that something was processed before he got 404 msg.

Comment: content of 'IF' means that you can simply use  `header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
    echo "<h1>Error 404 Not Found</h1>";
    echo "The page that you have requested could not be found.";
    exit(); `

Comment: So as i understand the event sequence is as following: Php define a header, The browser get response with the 404 header(I assume that mabye for few miliseconds the browser does show the 404 error), But then becouse i didnt exit; php send the rest of the file that replace the 404 error, Am i right?

Answer (score 1):

> why should i use the exit After the 404 header

So that no further code will be executed. If there isn't any then, fine, it isn't necessary *in this case*. It's a good habit to get into though.

> Also why with the BOM i dont get "headers already sent error"

You didn't configure your PHP installation to show errors and notices to the end user.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, About the 404 header if you can please tell me why only when i kill the rest off the code with (exit), Why only then i get the 404 what does the server return to the browser. And about the "headers already send" you are right.

Comment: I cant understand why the browser will read the 404 header only if i exit the script.