# No 404 after URL rewrite in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404

After rewriting all my url rules, everything that is passed is treated as a rewrite rule this results in no 404 pages ever! How can I serve 404 pages for pages that are not found i.e. example.com/books is url rewritten which is fine. However example.com/dfersfn isnt but this is also served and 404 is sent. Heres the content from my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule \.(css|jpe?g|gif|png|js|ico|svg)$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/f1/" [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/f2/" [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/f3/"
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*?)/?$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ book.php?slug=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/(.*)/? read.php?slug=$1&cslug=$2 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this in your `book.php` and `read.php` scripts. When you check for the "slug" and "cslug" in the database or whatever, if they don't exist, have the *script itself return a 404* via:

```
header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
```

THere's more info in this SO question: [Why won't my PHP app send a 404 error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437256/sending-a-404-error-in-php)