# .htaccess redirect to 404 if no match

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I've tried a few threads, but can'y seem to match what I need.

I have some htaccess code to serve a category page as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ category.php?s=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The QSA flag is on there to basically serve some filters to the page.
I only have 4 categories, so for arguments sake my category URL's will be:

```
http://domain.co.uk/category-url-1
http://domain.co.uk/category-url-2
http://domain.co.uk/category-url-3
http://domain.co.uk/category-url-4
```

The problem I am having and can't resolve is that I need to match these categories in htaccess and if they don't exist, then redirect to a 404 page. The category URL's will not change, so I can hard code this.

Currently on my category page, I have the PHP code:

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
header("Location: /404.php");
```

... if a match isn't found... but technically all this is doing is showing as a 302 as the category page exists and is processing the code first. I've checked these headers online and they give the 302.

Is there a way to hard code this in htaccess, if those categories above are not matched?

Comment: These are response headers, so if they are placed **before** any output is being generated, it should works as expected. Can you show us the code where you're using them?

Comment: `mod_rewrite` simply isn't meant to be aware of the response, just the request. Your best approach here would be to let `mod_rewrite` do it's work and trigger a 404 response in PHP code because PHP is the only one that knows if a rewritten resource is available (except if it physically exists on the server).

Comment: @unixarmy, Yup, they are. This all happens before anything is outputted. So DB Connection - > check category, if not match - set header and exit, if match, echo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because, from what I understand of your question the mod_rewrite will always goto a page that does exist (category.php), you have to set the 404 error generation within the category.php page,

Don't bother setting the 404 error header separately, simply

```
    if (no match with categories){
     //header("Location:404.php",TRUE, 404);
      header("Location:404.php");
      exit;
    }
```

From what I know of .htaccess it can't read if the data that it is processing (the category URL) is valid or not, as in, it can't tell you if the category is genuine or false because that is something that can only be defined by the PHP script.

*sorry I missed out the `Location:` part of the header*

### update

I think the loop that you reference, David, is that while the PHP file redirects to the 404.php page, the .htaccess is trying to match this to your rewrite rules, so you need to add checks to only rewrite URLs that are not referencing files or folders that already exist so, in your .htaccess :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ category.php?s=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This will only rewrite URLs if they do not point to a file or folder that exists before the rewrite.

### Update edit 2

The issue develops that now the OP wants the errors of the 404 pages to be noticed as 404 errors by the SEO aspects of the website, this is not done by `header("Location:")` because by its nature header location is a redirect.

So:
Reading up on here: [Why won't my PHP app send a 404 error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437256/why-wont-my-php-app-send-a-404-error) I think the issue is that because PHP sets the status code to 404, file not found, that then it ***becomes that PHP pages responsibility to output a 404 file***. So rather than setting a header Location redirect, the header should be set as a 404 error header and then after the header the 404 error page can be output on the category.php page as an include in the category page,

So, solution, when the category.php page has a invalid category call, it needs to output a header with a 404 in it:

```
header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
```

immediately followed by the category page outputting the message to the browser, which will be including the 404.php

such as :

```
<?php
if (!category match){
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
    include "404.php";
}
```

I do not know how your 404.php is set up but you may need to adjust the code to output the include file with a return value in the `404.php`,
This should then cause the incorrect category codes to be displayed with 404 error headers for SEO purposes.

Comment: Thanks for this. It gives me an Internal Server Error though. I'm assuming it is for a later version of PHP than the server is running.

Comment: the internal server error probably isn't caused by the PHP, read up on http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php @David . Please make sure the address of the `404.php` page is correct, the address will need to be relative to the category.php file location **or** to the `$_SERVER['Document_root']`

Comment: @David sorry I saw I had a syntax typo... fixed now

Comment: closer, I don't get an Internal Error, but it doesn't redirect either. Seems like it is stuck in a loop as the online response checker also bombs out.

Comment: @David you'll have to show more of your PHP code then to establish what the loop is

Comment: to remove the element of doubt, I have moved the above code to a unique file to mimic a failure, so all I have is `<? if($x != 1){ header("Location: /404.php",TRUE, 404);
     exit; } ?>` - which will always divert to a 404, nothing else in the page.

Comment: so, what's happening when it runs? also remove the `/` from the header too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84705/discussion-between-david-and-martin).

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP you should check if its category-url-1, 2, 3 o 4. You can do this by creating an array in your PHP document f.e.:

```
<!-- language: lang-php -->
$allowed_categories = array('category-url-1'
                             ,'category-url-2'
                             ,'category-url-3'
                             ,'category-url-4'
                           );

if (!empty($_GET['s']) && in_array($_GET['s'], $allowed_categories))
{
    echo 'Yes! The category exists!';
}
else
{
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
    echo 'The page is not found!';
}
```

If you want to redirect it to a specific 404.php file, then a header with a redirect is enough. You have to make sure, sending the 404 header is specified in your 404.php file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's not quite what I am after though. My above code works in what I need it to do by being visible to the user. It checks the category, sets the header and redirects to the 404 page... but when I run it through an online HTTP header check: http://httpstatus.io/ for example it gives me a 302 and then a 200 for the 404.php page. I need the 302 to be a 404, so Google can see it.