# How to redirect 404 error to 404.php page?

Tags: php

I need help in php. I am making one portal website in Core Php. I had created 404 page and .htaccess file.

404.php:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>404 Error - Page Not Found</title>
  </head>
  <body>404 Error - Page Not Found!</body>
</html>
```

.htaccess:

```
Redirect 404 /404.php
```

But this is not working. If I use this code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /404.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

It shows internal server error.

Here is my website: http://jobguide.australianenglishcenter.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in your .htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://jobguide.australianenglishcenter.com/404/

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/404/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ <YourRelativePathToPHPFile>/404.php [L]
```

Here,The ErrorDocument redirects all 404s to a specific URL

The Rewrite rules map that URL to your actual 404.php script. The RewriteCond regular expressions can be made more generic if you want, but I think you have to explicitly define all ErrorDocument codes you want to override.

NOTE: Replace

Comment: this is what i am using in .htaccess...But not working

Comment: there is nothing on jobguide.australianenglishcenter.com/404 . Are you using the correct path ?

Comment: yes you can check this link: jobguide.australianenglishcenter.com/404.php

Comment: I had used your code and it working but i is not redirecting to my 404 page. here is the link of my website please check http://jobguide.australianenglishcenter.com/

Comment: RewriteEngine On 
 RewriteBase / RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/404/$ 
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://jobguide.australianenglishcenter.com/404.php [L]

Comment: Use local relative file path instead of http URL in rewrite rule.. Rewrite rule works locally on your server.

Comment: what is local relative path?

Comment: Did you figure it out yet? It's like /folder/sub_folder/filename

Comment: no dear , i  had used relative path but still not redirecting to 404.php

Comment: please check your server's redirection rules.. might be you are over-riding somewhere

Answer (score 5):

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/404/
```

add this line to htaccess and change the url

Comment: can i see your htaccess

Comment: yes , this is the only code i am adding in .htaccess

Comment: ErrorDocument 404 http://jobguide.australianenglishcenter.com/404.php

try adding http:// if it doesnot work, check php config whether rewrite module is installed on ur server or not

Comment: i am using http:// but not working. I also think so that there is some server issue. I had made this project from scratch .So if i need to add php config file in my project what to do?

Comment: create a new file, add this piece of code : <?php phpinfo(); ?> and give the link of that file , will check the config once

Comment: i had put this code in new php file here is the link : http://jobguide.australianenglishcenter.com/phpconfig.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91809/discussion-between-jaswinder-kaur-and-manojgeek).

Answer (score 3):

the htacces should look like

```
ErrorDocument 404 /page404.php
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the rewrite engine on. Then customize a php page to handle the 404 error. Refer the below code

```
RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example.com/your-404-custom-file-name.php
```

Answer (score 0):

call the function :

```
http_send_status(404);
```

Comment: in htaccess file and see given link for more help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437256/why-wont-my-php-app-send-a-404-error

Comment: use following code in htaccess file ErrorDocument 404 https://www.yourdomainname/404.html
# or map them to one error document:
# ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

Answer (score 0):

you can also use below to make all 404 requrest redirect to specific page

```
FallbackResource /index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the method `http_response_code(int code)`.
[Here is the method documentation.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code in 404.php in which you can create your own error page...

```
<?php header('Location: /directory/page-name/'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Open Your htaccess and insert this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule \.php$ - [R=404]
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.yoursite.com/404.php
```

This works for me. I don't use any CMS, and my website in php too.

Answer (score -1):

I think a simple way to add a 404, 505, or other pages in your project just put the simple thing in your .htaccess file which is in the project root folder and paste the  simple line

```
RewriteEngine on
errordocument 404 http://localhost/MVC_Project2/404.php
```